# How can i get IfcOpenShell for python to write with the same unicode as the file it reads?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, ifc, ifc-open-shell

I'm using IfcOpenshell to read an .ifc file. make some changes, then write it to a new .ifc file. But IfcOpenshell is not writing the unicode the same way as it reads it.

I'm creating a script taht adds a pset with properties to each ifcelement. the value of these properties are copied from existing properties. So basically i'm creating a pset that gathers chosen information to a single place.
This has worked great until the existing values contained unicode utf-8.
It is read and decoded to show the correct value when printed, but it does not write the unicode the same way as it reads it.
I tried changing the unicode used in PyCharm, no luck. I found simular posts elsewhere without finding a fix. 
From what i've read elsewhere it has something to do with the unicode encoder/decoder IfcOpenshell use, but i cant be sure.

```
def mk_pset():
    global param_name
    global param_type
    global max_row
    global param_map
    wb = load_workbook(b)
    sheet = wb.active
    max_row = sheet.max_row
    max_column = sheet.max_column
    param_name = []
    param_type = []
    param_map=[]
    global pset_name
    pset_name = sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value
    for pm in range(2, max_row+1):
        param_name.append((sheet.cell(pm, 2)).value)
        param_type.append((sheet.cell(pm, 3)).value)
        param_map.append((sheet.cell(pm,4)).value)
    print(param_type,' - ',len(param_type))
    print(param_name,' - ',len(param_name))
    create_pset()



def create_pset():

    ifcfile = ifcopenshell.open(ifc_loc)
    create_guid = lambda: ifcopenshell.guid.compress(uuid.uuid1().hex)
    owner_history = ifcfile.by_type("IfcOwnerHistory")[0]
    element = ifcfile.by_type("IfcElement")
    sets = ifcfile.by_type("IfcPropertySet")
    list = []
    for sett in sets:
        list.append(sett.Name)
    myset = set(list)
    global antall_parametere
    global index
    index = 0
    antall_parametere = len(param_name)

    if pset_name not in myset:
        property_values = []
        tot_elem = (len(element))
        cur_elem = 1
        for e in element:
            start_time_e=time.time()
            if not e.is_a() == 'IfcOpeningElement':
                type_element.append(e.is_a())
                for rel_e in e.IsDefinedBy:
                    if rel_e.is_a('IfcRelDefinesByProperties'):
                        if not rel_e[5][4] == None:
                            index = 0
                            while index < antall_parametere:
                                try:
                                    ind1 = 0
                                    antall_ind1 = len(rel_e[5][4])
                                    while ind1 < antall_ind1:
                                        if rel_e[5][4][ind1][0] == param_map[index]:
                                            try:
                                                if not rel_e[5][4][ind1][2]==None:
                                                    p_type = rel_e[5][4][ind1][2].is_a()
                                                    p_verdi =rel_e[5][4][ind1][2][0]
                                                    p_t=param_type[index]
                                                    property_values.append(ifcfile.createIfcPropertySingleValue(param_name[index], param_name[index],ifcfile.create_entity(p_type,p_verdi),None),)
                                                    ind1 += 1
                                                else:
                                                    ind1 +=1
                                            except TypeError:
                                                pass
                                                break
                                        else:
                                            ind1 += 1
                                except AttributeError and IndexError:
                                    pass
                                index += 1
                            index = 0
            property_set = ifcfile.createIfcPropertySet(create_guid(), owner_history, pset_name, pset_name,property_values)
            ifcfile.createIfcRelDefinesByProperties(create_guid(), owner_history, None, None, [e], property_set)
            ifc_loc_edit = str(ifc_loc.replace(".ifc", "_Edited.ifc"))
            property_values = []
            print(cur_elem, ' av ', tot_elem, ' elementer ferdig. ',int(tot_elem-cur_elem),'elementer gjenstår. Det tok ',format(time.time()-start_time_e),' sekunder')
            cur_elem += 1
        ifcfile.write(ifc_loc_edit)
    else:
        ###print("Pset finnes")
        sg.PopupError("Pset er allerede oprettet i modell.")
```

I expect p_verdi written to be equal to the p_verdi read.

Original read (D\X2\00F8\X0\r):

```
#2921= IFCBUILDINGELEMENTPROXYTYPE('3QPADpsq71CHeCe7e3GDm5',#32,'D\X2\00F8\X0\r',$,$,$,$,'DA64A373-DB41-C131-1A0C-A07A0340DC05',$,.NOTDEFINED.);
```

Written (D\X4\000000F8\X0\r):

```
#2921=IFCBUILDINGELEMENTPROXYTYPE('3QPADpsq71CHeCe7e3GDm5',#32,'D\X4\000000F8\X0\r',$,$,$,$,'DA64A373-DB41-C131-1A0C-A07A0340DC05',$,.NOTDEFINED.);
```

Decoded to "Dør"

this happens to hard spaceing also:

```
('2\X2\00A0\X0\090')
```

prints correctly as:('2 090')

gets written:

```
('2\X4\000000A0\X0\090')
```

written form is unreadable by my ifc using software.

Comment: Sorry about the big types. Copy/Paste result.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. How do you instantiate the variables `rel_e`, `param_map`, `param_type`, `ifcfile`, `property_values`...?

Comment: Edited to contain more of the code. main packages is 'ifcopenshell' and 'openpyxl'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much an answere as a workaround.

After more research i found out that most IFC reading software seems to not support X4 coding, so i made a workaround with regex. Basically finding everything and replacing \X4\0000 with \X2. This has worked with  all the spec chars i've encountered so far. But as stated, is just a workaround that probably wont work for everyone.

```
def X4trans_2(target_file,temp_fil):
from re import findall
from os import remove,rename
dec_file = target_file.replace('.ifc', '_dec.ifc')
tempname = target_file
dec_list = []
with open(temp_fil, 'r+') as r,open(dec_file, 'w', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    for line in r:
        findX4 = findall(r'\\X4\\0000+[\w]+\\X0\\', str(line))
        if findX4:
            for fx in findX4:
                X4 = str(fx)
                newX = str(fx).replace('\\X4\\0000', '\X2\\')
                line = line.replace(str(X4), newX)  # print ('Fant X4')
        f.writelines(line)
remove(temp_fil)
try:
    remove(target_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

rename(dec_file,tempname)
```

It basically opens the ifc as text, find and replace X4 with X2 and writes it again.